# DISM: Unable to pass esd file

Tags: windows, windows-update

I am having a problem to pass an esd-File to dism for the restorehealth command.
Here is my call:

> dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /Source:esd:D:\sources\install.esd /limitaccess

However, the cbs.log-File indicates that a wrong path (the current directory is added to the path of the file) is used when trying to access the file:

> 2020-04-21 15:40:06, Info                  CBS    Exec: Addsource called, Session: 30808034_1579090974, Client: DISM Package Manager Provider, from GPO: No, Path: C:\Windows\System32\esd:D:\sources\install.esd
>   2020-04-21 15:40:06, Warning               CBS    The alternate source path directory could not be accessed [HRESULT = 0x8007007b - ERROR_INVALID_NAME]

Comment: Can you put the ESD file on drive C: ?  Is the ESD file the exact match for your Windows 10 build (it needs to be)?   Can you run DISM from the source already on your computer?  DISM has been much improved in the last 2 or 3 years.

Comment: Your missing a space between the two arguments based on the message.  It's attempting to locate `C:\Windows\System32\esd:D:\sources\install.esd` which of course is an invalid path name.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Ramhound, where would I have to add that space in the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up converting the esd file to a WIM-file, then the path was read out correct by dism